# Freescale TPM Input Capture Mode

Tags: arm, driver, cortex-m

I have an FRDM-KL26 MCU and I'm writing a TPM/PWM driver, but can't accomplish it, so I have a couple of questions:

1.TPM0 has 5 channels.It is possible to use all of these channels as input capture ?

2.I already configured one channel for input capture mode, but i can`t clear TOF(timer overflow flag) register in ISR. ( it is because another overflow occurred before i cleared first time ?)

Example of isr:

void Io_Tpm_Tpm1Isr(void)
{

```
if(TPM_STATUS_REG(TPM1) & TPM_STATUS_TOF_MASK){                                         /* check if TOF is set */
    TPM1_SC |= TPM_SC_TOF_MASK; /* Delete the TOF flag such that the IRQ ends */
}

if( TPM_STATUS_REG(TPM1) & TPM_STATUS_CH0F_MASK ){                                      /* CHANNEL 0*/
    TPM_CnSC_REG(TPM1,IO_TPM_CHANNEL0) |=  TPM_CnSC_CHF_MASK;                           /*Clear CHF  - event occurred */

}else if(TPM_STATUS_REG(TPM1) & TPM_STATUS_CH1F_MASK){                                  /* CHANNEL 1*/
    TPM_CnSC_REG(TPM1,IO_TPM_CHANNEL1) |=  TPM_CnSC_CHF_MASK;                           /*Clear CHF  - event occurred */
}
```

}